# show only difference using imagemagick compare

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick compare to compare two images and get their diff. I have 2 questions:

1. I want to get a transparent result image with only the diff parts, nothing else. Not white - transparent.
2. Is it possible to get the diff of only one image instead of both ?

Thanks!

Comment: How can you get the difference of one image? Difference from what?

Comment: I think that the OP should change the composting method to get what he wants in his 2nd question.

My problem is that I don’t get the transparent background, it’s black instead; what can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose you start with these two images:

```
convert -size 256x256 xc:black -fill white -draw "circle 100,100 120,100" a.png
```

[image]

and

```
convert -size 256x256 xc:black -fill white -draw "circle 120,120 140,140" b.png
```

[image]

Then you can get the differences in red on a transparent background like this:

```
compare a.png b.png -highlight-color red -lowlight-color none -compose src diff.png
```

[image]

I have overlaid it onto a checkerboard like Photoshop does so you can see the checkerboard through the transparency.

As regards your second question, I have no idea how you can get the difference between a single image? Difference from what?